# How do I build and deploy a simple mono C# web api to an ubuntu server?

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, asp.net-web-api, monodevelop

I have an ubuntu instance with mono installed and would like to install a simple api project that is on another computer.

I do not have the "Web Deployment Settings" options referenced in this article.
http://www.monodevelop.com/documentation/creating-aspnet-projects/

How do I move my project to the server and start it up?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/12/jexus-web-server-and-asp-net-cross-platform/ The video clips show how to install Jexus web server and run a simple MVC5 web app. It also applies to Web API apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this properly you might want to look into deployment tools such as Capistrano or Chef.

First, you'll want to create your Mono app as a console application. Linux can just run your executable, there isn't an easy web host environment like IIS for Mono apps (yet). This of course means your app could exit on an exception, so ensure you have adequate defensive coding to avoid that happening.

Basically, to move the files you can use SCP, just `scp -R <directory> <username>@<server>:/<path_to_copy_to>`. Once you've got the files there you then need to start the app, and I'm guessing you want to run it as a service, not just on-demand. In order to do this you'll need to create an [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) script. You'll want to create a job for starting, stopping and maybe restarting your app.

If you add it to the right runlevels it will automatically start on boot and stop on shutdown.

Comment: Mono web apps can run on Apache (mod_mono), nginx (via FastCGI), or Jexus web server (fully integrated). So never a need to convert to a console app.

Comment: If you're going to run it through Nginx you could use Kestrel rather than FastCGI - http://druss.co/2015/06/asp-net-5-kestrel-nginx-web-server-on-linux/

Comment: .NET Core is not Mono though.